# How to really set foreground window using Winapi?

Tags: qt, winapi

OS: Windows 10

I have very simple GUI application in Qt. In this app I only set the window name to "tmpAppName".

Now I would like to run the second app which set the first App to foreground ( tmpAppName ).

My second App:

```
    auto hwndAppToForeground = FindWindowExA(0,0,0,"tmpAppName");
    if(!hwndAppToForeground)
    {
        qDebug()<<"No window with name tmpAppName";
        exit(0);
    }

    auto foregroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();

    Sleep(5000);


    if(foregroundWindow!=hwndAppToForeground)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(hwndAppToForeground);
        SetActiveWindow(hwndAppToForeground);
        SetFocus(hwndAppToForeground);
        SetWindowPos(hwndAppToForeground, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
    }
```

I using Sleep(5000) because during that time I set other application in the foreground ( for example Audacity ).

The line:

```
SetWindowPos(hwndAppToForeground, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

is very helpfull, but I get window in the foreground but not active and when I check which window is in the foreground I get something different then "tmpAppName":

[image: nter image description here]

And I would like to achieve:

[image]

Comment: [Foreground activation permission is like love: You can’t steal it, it has to be given to you](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090220-00/?p=19083).

Comment: Wow. Thank you  @IInspectable But is there any way to achieve what I want? ;)

Comment: [AllowSetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-allowsetforegroundwindow).